# Where is Magento's data for custom modules in admin panel contained?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, magento-layout-xml

I made a module for admin panel magento and added fields.

All fields (text, textarea, etc) and their values are showing correctly. When I save it, they are also getting saved.

I cleared session, cookies and browser history and all. The values are still there. That means values getting saved in database.

But since I didn't provide any database name, I don't know where those values are persisted.

Can anyone tell me where the data is persisted?

Answer (score 0):

Magento takes care of persisting the admin configuration automatically. The field values are stored in the core_config_data table.